# Java Profiler for memory allocation

Tags: java, memory, profiler

I am looking for a java profiler in which I can locate; at what methods the maximum allocation is taking place. I have tested Java Mission Control and YourKit but they only show the class whose instance the object is and not the method in which it is allocated.
But I am new to profiling and might have missed some features of these profilers.

Any help with this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JProfiler?
I think it's the most common Profiler for Java apps.

Comment: I am working with openjdk14 and jprofiler only works up oo jdk11.

Comment: No, the current version of JProfiler supports Java 16 as well. Generally JProfiler will support new Java versions long before they are released.

Comment: After downloading jprofiler script for linux from https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files. I get the following error:

No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 11.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

Comment: So now you should upgrade the JVM on your machine, and set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned in the previous comment that I am using OpenJDK14